# Getting Association through self-inheriting STI model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails app I have Users and Forms.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admin_roles
  #desired association below
  #has_many :forms, through: :admin_roles
end
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :department
end
```

The Users need to administrate the Forms through any level of an Organization.

```
class AdminRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :user
end
```

If assigned to a non-department organization the forms they have control over should come through the child departments.

The Forms are assigned to a departmental level only.
My model for the Organization is an STI model of 3 levels: market>subdomain>department

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :org_level
  has_many :admin_roles
end
class Department < Organization
  belongs_to :sub_domain, primary_key: :id, foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :forms
end
class SubDomain < Organization
  belongs_to :market, primary_key: :id, foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :departments
end
class Market < Organization
  has_many :sub_domains
end
```

The desired capability is to do `user.forms` and get all the associated forms back.

For example: Given there was a hierarchy of FooMarket>BarDomain>LoremDepartment
and a Form associated to LoremDepartment.
If a User is then tied to any of those 3 Organizations through the AdminRole it would allow for the return of the LoremDepartment Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to necessarily do it with associations ? u can always define an instance method in user model and back track it to forms.
But before that, just a reminder, you have to mention the foreign key in both the models for the association to work both ways.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :admin_roles
  has_many :organizations, :through => :admin_roles

  def forms
    organizations.map(&:forms).flatten.uniq
  end
end

class Department < Organization
  belongs_to :sub_domain, primary_key: :id, foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :forms, :foreign_key => :organization_id
end

class SubDomain < Organization
  belongs_to :market, primary_key: :id, foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :departments, foreign_key: :parent_id

  def forms
    departments.map(&:forms).flatten
  end
end

class Market < Organization
  has_many :sub_domains, foreign_key: :parent_id

  def forms
    sub_domains.map(&:forms).flatten
  end

end
```

I tested this and it does work. But kinda round about.

Comment: Awesome answer :D.    Just one question, I might need to go back from Forms to Users.  Would I just build a similar call stack going the other way through?

Comment: Uhmm first you need to get associations right. Form has_one Department make that to Form belongs to department coz u already have has many.  And you have to do something like this . Form will belong to a department and if you have has many belongs to in Organization to User then you can directly do form_object.department.users. For going through the other two STI models you need to work it out a bit.

Comment: and do accept the answer if it works for you. I actually created these models and worked em out ;) :D

Comment: Yea I was thinking I would need to get the Dept, and its hierarchical org structure and then compare those to the AdminRoles table to see what users had access.